# Cannot connect to IBM Bluemix from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, hybrid, ibm-cloud-tools

I am trying to connect to Bluemix via eclipse using Bluemix Tools for Exclipse but while creating server it is giving error that email or password is wrong. Although I use same credentials to login in Bluemix. Please suggest.

Comment: What Eclipse version do you run ?

Comment: Have you tried to login with cf cli?

Comment: Its working now. I had to reset my id. I have another problem. I have created an IBM MobileFirst Project in eclipse and I want to deploy it in IBM Bluemix, is there any way to do that? I am using Windows 7, Eclipse Luna and jdk 1.7

Comment: this is a totally different question, regarding the MobileFirst Server. if I were you I would create a MobileFirst Server on Bluemix (by choosing the MobileFirst Foundation service from the catalog) and use the mfpdev cli to upload it to the mf server running on bluemix. check the docs for more information - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilefoundation/index.html?pos=2

Answer (score 0):

OK! So you have not succeeded with creating a server yet then try this.

Install the latest [Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cloud-foundry-integration-eclipse).
Restart Eclipse and now try to add the server by cloud foundry and use `api.ng.bluemix.net` for server as shown **[here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/deploy-bluemix-application-that-uses-services/)**

Comment: and you did try with your IBM ID ? Make sure you use the IBM ID